# Is there any way while using redis we could write behind to hbase

Tags: node.js, redis, hbase

As far as i know redis only write-behind in a binary file. but our software requirement is to write behind to hbase using any compatible distributed maps(redis).Is there any way while using redis we could write behind to hbase.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to customize the way that the file writes. It is going to write to disk and there isn't much you can do about that.

What you should do instead is have an external scheduled process (using cron, perhaps) that periodically takes the Redis file and then dumps it into HBase.

Few ways you can customize this process to be more robust, if it fits your situation and needs:

- Execute a [BGSAVE](http://redis.io/commands/bgsave) before starting the ingest process to be sure you have an up-to-date dump.
- do an `md5sum` on the file before ingesting it into HBase. Check to see that the `md5sum` has changed since the last time you've processed it. This might be useful if the data in your Redis instance isn't changing very often.
- Use an [append only file](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) dump instead. This way, you can keep track of what you have ingested into HBase already, and then only update to the changes. You'll just have to keep track of what line you left off at last time. This would be good if you don't want to dump your HBase table every time and reload it.

Comment: @Donald Miner, when you say "takes the redis file and then dumps it into HBase", you meant read the redis file,parse it and then PUT it to HBase format, right?